# User uploads with fixed per user quota in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm running a DotNetNuke 7.0 Community Edition installation and I'm currently looking for a way of allowing users to upload own content into their very own directory. I would also like the users to have a maximum storage limit of for instance 2GB. Perhaps there already is an in-built solution for this scenario but I'm also willing to spend money for a commercial module.

So I've not found an on-board setting allowing me to set a per-user-quota, neither have I been able to find a module available in the store http://store.dnnsoftware.com for several hours now.

I even decompiled the DotNetNuke.dll in my installation directory and noticed it has members called **UserQuota** in *DotNetNuke.Portals.PortalSettings* and *DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalInfo* but I still failed to find where to define a quota for my users. Is this a Professional/Enterprise feature only by any chance?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If there's no such module I can also write a custom module, but instead of reinvent the wheel I'd love to hear your ideas first.

Thanks.

---

**For future reference:**
I ended up coding a custom DNN upload plugin which stores all files users upload into their own directory and controls the maximum storage space each of these users has. If you need this for an own project just drop me a message for the .zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetNuke has a portal level quota for file-space that you can set.  This is available under "Admin" -> "Site Settings" -> "Host Settings" (On Advanced Tab).

However, this is for the entire portal.  I am not aware of any user specific, or folder specific quota mechanism for DotNetNuke.

Comment: Alright, many thanks for your response. In this case a custom module will be needed I guess.